# Install script with restart and continue

Tags: installation, scripts

I want to create an script lihe this:

```
command_1
command_2
...
command_n

restart

command_n+1
command_n+2
...
command_m
```

It is possible in bash ?

Answer (score 2):

In that case you create a file where you store your last command.
And create a script that checks if the file exists and contains a line.
If so, the last time your script has run and the it must compleet.

When the file doesn't exists or is empty, do nothin. When the file contains a command, run the follow up command.

```
# Determine if last_command.txt exists
if [ -f last_command.txt ]; then
    # Extract the last line out of the file
    last_command=$(head -n 1 last_command.txt)

    # Check if last_command is set, that is the next command has to be executed.
    if [ ! -z $last_command ]; then 
        # Excecute the next command. 
    fi
else
   # Do nothing.
fi
```

Place the next line before the reboot command.

```
# Writes <Last command> to last_command.txt. Care for proper permissions!
echo "<Last command>" > last_command.txt

reboot
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you be a little more specific? Possibly an example of such :
command_1 ; 
reboot ; 
command_2  ?  
And where to put the file? in /etc/RC0.d, elsewhere ?  
thanks

Comment: Addendum : this script is used for an single installation process.

Comment: I understand. But where I put that file? Then who check the file after reboot? This mechanism'm interested in ... I can create two executable files (before reboot and after reboot). But the mechanism to access / identify correct file (ecen last_command.txt) after reboot is the big problem ...

Comment: Path: wherever you want to put it. Mechanism: run at every boot the (modified) script.

Answer (score 1):

I create two files:
`script_before_reboot` and `script_after_reboot`

`script_before_reboot`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cale=`dirname $0`
sudo update-rc.d -f script_after_reboot remove
cp $cale"/script_after_reboot" /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/script_after_reboot
sudo update-rc.d script_after_reboot defaults 90

sudo rm /etc/rc0.d/K90script_after_reboot
sudo rm /etc/rc1.d/K90script_after_reboot
sudo rm /etc/rc3.d/S90script_after_reboot
sudo rm /etc/rc4.d/S90script_after_reboot
sudo rm /etc/rc5.d/S90script_after_reboot
sudo rm /etc/rc6.d/K90script_after_reboot

command_1
command_2
...
command_n
sudo reboot
```

`script_after_reboot`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
command_1
command_2
...
command_n
sudo update-rc.d -f script_after_reboot remove
# or, if you need another reboot :
# sudo update-rc.d -f script_after_reboot remove && sudo reboot
exit 0
```

In this way `script_before_reboot` runs with root permissions (`sudo /path/script_before_reboot`).
After reboot the script `script_after_reboot` runs from its symlink `/etc/rc2.d/script_after_reboot`. After execution, this script is automatically deleted, together with its own symlink found in `/etc/rc2.d`. That's all.